# running react native project in android emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

when i'm trying to run my react native project after reaching to 99% of execation i throw an error that my android development environment is not setup...
and in emulator i got warning to updation of android emulator... how can i apdate my emulator

[how can i resolve this??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7my05.png))

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you can update by going to the `SDK Manager` and checking if there are available updates there. Namely you'd want to update your `SDK Build-Tools` which is the second tab on that screen

[image: Preferences > Android SDK]

If you've already updated there and you're still getting this message, you could try deleting the `Virtual Devices` you made and making new ones.

Here's a video that might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAIIyNGk_KA